# How to show Fixed Number of Rows in a listView

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to display only 5 rows in a `ListView` and rest of them should be `scrollable`.So far i have tried this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/txtFilename"
        android:layout_width="375dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarSize="2dp"
        android:

        /> 



     <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btnOk"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="OK"/>

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="CANCEL"/>
    </LinearLayout>  


</LinearLayout>
```

and in `java code`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView list1;

    private String array[] = { "Iphone", "Tutorials", "Gallery", "Android",

    "item 1", "item 2", "item3", "item 4" };
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //parentLayout.add(childLayout);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

        // By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in

        // list.

        list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));

    }
```

have any idea how to achieve it

Comment: Android mobile comes in different screen size. so in small size screen how can u show 5 items.

Comment: You can check this:This is possibly duplicate of:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509929/android-how-to-set-fixed-no5-of-rows-shows-in-listview-then-after-scroll

Comment: @Sandy these i have already checked not helpful for me.

Comment: you can use two different listview make first one fixed and remaining item in next listview

Comment: @vsk  assume that i am not using small screen mobile devices iam using  Tablets.

Comment: @IftikarUrrhmanKhan that will cause code complexity in my app so not preferable. if have any good idea you can post the  code.

Comment: i think for that you need to set listviews height to fixed size..

Comment: give me a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i am Just Modifying Your `Layout` just check it out!!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/txtFilename"
        android:layout_width="375dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />
<LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="300dip">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarSize="2dp"


        /> 


</LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btnOk"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="OK"/>

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="CANCEL"/>
    </LinearLayout>  


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for my time its exactly what i want.

Answer (score -1):

I have written Demo for this Like:

if you want to fix Height of `ListView` to 5 items. then you have to set Height of `ListView`  pragmatically by calculating `listItems` height.

First you need to create Layout for List Item and give it some fixed height, here i'm added height in `Tag` cause `runtime` i was getting layouts height as 0.

This is `ListItem` Layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:tag="40"
    android:layout_height="40dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="XXX"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text"
        android:text="ZZZ"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and to set Height of ListView:

```
list    =   (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, setter);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);        

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lstViewParams = (LayoutParams) list.getLayoutParams();        
    View lisItemInflatedView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.item, null);        
    RelativeLayout relLayoutInLstItem = (RelativeLayout) lisItemInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);       
    final float scale = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int pixels = (int) ( Integer.parseInt( relLayoutInLstItem.getTag().toString() ) * scale + 0.5f);    
    int listHeigt = pixels  * 5 + 5;       
    lstViewParams.height = listHeigt;
```

here's the screenshot..

[image]

Hope this will Help.

Comment: its my ListItem.. where i can have name and contact no. u need to worry about how many views are there in your list item. just get height of your list item and multiply it..

Comment: i can't. i have given u more than enough. you need to put some effort.

Comment: its very simple if you want to fixed number of Listview Items in listview  you can put the listview in a linearlayout.

Comment: if he want to display 5 items approx he can use 300dip that will display nearly 5 Items and the rest of will come as scrollable if he has more than 5 Items.