# Android Extra Empty Space Under My Listview Issue

Tags: android, listview

i need some help in my android application. I have 2 listviews inside scrollview. I want my listviews unscrollable to see all my listview items. So here is my code to list all items:

```
public class CustomList extends ListView
{

boolean expanded = false;

public CustomList(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public CustomList(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomList(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public boolean isExpanded()
{
    return expanded;
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
    if (isExpanded())
    {
        // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
        // But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are
        // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    else
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
{
    this.expanded = expanded;
}
}
```

Here is my .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scroll"
android:paddingLeft="12dp"
android:paddingRight="12dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
   tools:context="com.example.cagri.mobilyateknikservis.BildirimActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/activity_bildirim">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="Müşteri:"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/MusteriAdi"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtMusteri"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textAlignment="textStart" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Hizmet Tipi:"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/HizmetTipi"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtHizmetTipi"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textAlignment="textStart" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Sipariş Ref. No."
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/SiparisRef"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtSiparisRef"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textAlignment="textStart" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="Firma:"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Firma"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Firma"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtFirma"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Sipariş Tarihi:"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/SiparisTarihi"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Sipariş Tarihi"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtSiparisTarihi"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Teslim Tarihi:"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/TeslimTarihi"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Teslim Tarihi"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtTeslimTarihi"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="Depo:"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Depo"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Depo"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/txtDepo"
            android:layout_weight="0.98"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Telefon:"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Telefon"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Telefon"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/txtTelefon"
            android:layout_weight="8.5"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="Adres:"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/Adres"
            android:layout_weight="0.99"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Adres"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/txtAdres"
            android:layout_weight="14.01"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="Açıklama:"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/Aciklama"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Açıklama"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/txtAciklama"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:text="İŞLEMLER"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/Islemler"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_height="30dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="İşlem"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Islem"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:maxWidth="100dp"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:width="100dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Açıklama"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Aciklama2"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:minWidth="180dp"
            android:width="180dp"
            android:maxWidth="180dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Sonuç"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Sonuc"
            android:layout_weight="1.7"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Sonuç Tarihi"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/SonucTarihi"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.example.cagri.mobilyateknikservis.CustomList
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/lstIsl"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

    <TextView
        android:text="PARÇALAR"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Parcalar"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_height="30dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="Talep Tarihi"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textAlignment="textStart" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Parça"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Miktar"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

        <TextView
            android:text="İade Durumu"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textAlignment="textStart" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Açıklama"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Sonuç"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Sonuç Tarihi"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.example.cagri.mobilyateknikservis.CustomList
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/lstParcalar"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And my custom listview adapter:

```
public class ParcaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Parcalar> parcaBilgileri;

public ParcaAdapter(Activity activity, List<Parcalar> parca)
{
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)     activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    parcaBilgileri = parca;
}

public int getCount() {
    return parcaBilgileri.size();
}

public Parcalar getItem(int position) {
    return parcaBilgileri.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View satirView;
    satirView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parcalar_list, null);
    TextView txtTalepTarihi = (TextView)     satirView.findViewById(R.id.txtTalepTarihi);
    TextView txtParca = (TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.txtParca);
    TextView txtMiktar = (TextView)     satirView.findViewById(R.id.txtMiktar);
    TextView txtIadeDurumu = (TextView)     satirView.findViewById(R.id.txtIadeDurumu);
    TextView txtAciklama = (TextView)     satirView.findViewById(R.id.txtAciklama);
    TextView txtSonuc = (TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.txtSonuc);
    TextView txtSonucTarihi = (TextView)     satirView.findViewById(R.id.txtSonucTarihi);

    Parcalar bilgi = parcaBilgileri.get(position);

    txtTalepTarihi.setText(bilgi.gettaleptarihi());
    txtParca.setText(bilgi.getparca());
    txtMiktar.setText(bilgi.getmiktar());
    txtIadeDurumu.setText(bilgi.getiadedurumu());
    txtAciklama.setText(bilgi.getaciklama());
    txtSonuc.setText(bilgi.getsonuc());
    txtSonucTarihi.setText(bilgi.getsonuctarihi());

    return satirView;
}
}
```

Thanks for helping.

**Edit**: Screenshot for my app.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RecyclerView instead of ListView and for ScrollView use NestedScrollView. It is designed for this kind of scrolling. Another thing, give recyclerView height to be wrap_content for white space

Comment: Thanks for answer, i will try your solution.

Comment: I am not sure whats is the issue with you now but this is the way to do it. I have done it. Keep this recyclerView and nestedScrollView and look deep.

Answer (score 0):

No need to do this all code for this. You just need to change your list view heights based on child views. Just use simple adapter for this and after setAdapter call below method.

```
private void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView, int columns, int arrayPosition) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    boolean isSaved = false;
    int totalHeight = 0;
    int tempHeight = 10;
    int items = listAdapter.getCount();
    int rows = 0;

    View listItem = listAdapter.getView(0, null, listView);
    listItem.measure(0, 0);
    totalHeight = listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

    float x = 1;
    if (items > columns) {
        x = items / columns;
        if (arrayPosition == 0) {
            rows = (int) (x + 1);
        } else {
            rows = (int) (x + 3);
        }
        totalHeight *= rows;
        if (!isSaved) {
            tempHeight += rows;
            isSaved = true;
        }
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();

    params.height = totalHeight + (tempHeight * 4);

    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

modify params.height as per your need.

call this methid like this:

```
   setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(yourListView, 1, position);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i'm not sure i understand. I'm using custom listview to customize columns so i used custom adapter.

Comment: Its okay. But no need to use CustomList. You can do this with simple ListView directly.

Comment: You can also refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29225539/set-listview-height-dynamically-based-on-multiline-textview-inside-it This is same example like you did code.

Comment: When i use simple Listview, i couldn't see all my list items for example i have 4 items but i see only 2 items.

Comment: Then you need to do some mathematical calculation with params.height variable. Hope You will get success.

Comment: Understood. But what is position ?

Comment: Position is your listviews child position. for example if position is 0 - need to add 1 in x's value otherwise add 3 in x's value.